# How can i set item name in smartimageview if there is no network?

Tags: android, imageview, offline-mode

I am using smartimageview one of the best library to display image from url. When i cleared the app cache and load the page that contains the smartimageview in offline condition it shows nothing. So i want display at least the item name in the place of smart imageview. What I should do ?

Comment: Set a placeholder image on start, replace it when you have downloaded the image?

Comment: can i set name? because there is nothing in the the listview to recognize item other than this imageview.

Comment: Create a TextView on top of the ImageView, set the name to the TextView, then when the image is loaded, hide the TextView and show the ImageView...

Comment: But i do not getting any event to recognize whether it is loaded succesfully or not

Comment: This is hard to believe, and if it's true then it's most definitely not "one of the best library to display image from url"... somewhere this library will do .setImage() or something like that, I am sure.